# getting error while starting tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, tomcat

getting this error while starting tomcat 
publishing to tomcat v8.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem
Publishing the configuration...

```
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\context.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\server.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\tomcat-users.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/backup\web.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to run Tomcat from Eclipse, please try to start Eclipse as administrator. (Right click on shortcut -> "Run as Administrator")